# Poincaré inequality on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

On a compact subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the Poincaré inequality states
$$\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C \|\nabla u \|_{L^p(\Omega)}. \tag{1}$$
When we generalize to a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ with metric $g$ the inequality is given as:
$$\|u - \overline{u}\|_{L^p(M)} \leq C \|\nabla u\|_{L^p(M)}$$
where $$\overline{u} = \frac{1}{\text{Vol}_{(M,g)}} \int_M u \,d\text{Vol}_g. \tag{2}$$

I have two questions regarding this inequality.

1. Why are we able to omit the average value of $u$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as in (1) but not in general as in (2)?
2. Is the gradient in (2) interpreted as the Riemannian gradient with respect to $g$, i.e. $\nabla u = (\partial_i u) g^{ij}\partial_j $? In some texts (for example, Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*) he writes

> Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. If $f \in H^{1,2}(M)$ satisfies $\int_M f = 0$, then $$\|f\|_{L^2(M)} \leq \text{const Vol}(M)^{\frac1n}\|Df\|_{L^2(M)}.$$

It is not too clear what is $D$ in his notation, but judging by how it is used earlier in the text for $\mathbb{R}^n$ I assume he means a weak derivative. If so, I am confused on how the right-hand side of (2) should be interpreted. Should it be the norm of the Riemannian gradient (which depends on the metric $g$) or the weak derivative (which doesn't depend on the metric $g$)?

Comment: $\|Df(p)\|$ should be interpreted as the norm of the vector $\nabla f(p)$ using the Riemannian metric.

Comment: @Mason Thank you.

Comment: Note though that this norm is equivalent for all continuous metric tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't
2. Yes

It might help me a bit more if I knew where you're getting the statements of the theorems from - is it from Jost?

**(1)**

Looking at wikipedia, you'll notice that your inequality (1) only holds the Sobolev space of *traceless* functions $W^{1,p}_0$, which means the functions "go to zero at the boundary of $\Omega$" (quotes because the functions are officially only defined up to measure 0, so you need a different way of saying they are zero on the boundary). A more precise statement is that $W^{1,p}_0$ is the closure of $C^\infty_0$ of smooth functions which actually are zero on the boundary.

On the other hand you can also put the average value back into the inequality and not worry about the zero trace condition. (This is on wikipedia too. I'm also assuming $\Omega$ has nice enough boundary in both cases.)

You can come up with some counter example sequences of functions which break both cases. E.g. $u_n(x) = u(x) + n$ makes the integral on the left side of (1) large, but doesn't change the gradient.

**(2)**

If he says $f\in H^{1,2}(M)$ that means the weak derivative $Df$ exists.

Don't both norms depend on $g$?
I would imagine $|\nabla f|_g = |\mathrm d f|_g = |D f|_g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand now for (1). For (2), the result I've quoted is from Jost (Corollary A.1.2, page 574). Both norms would depend on $g$, but within each norm $\nabla f$ depends on $g$ since locally $\nabla f= (\partial_i f) g^{ij}\partial_j$, but I thought $Df$ does not.

Comment: The induced norm $g$ on $T^*M$ uses the inverse of $g$ on $TM$. So if you write out both $\nabla f$ and $\mathrm d f$ norms you'll see they are equal. Also I'm assuming $f$ is smooth or sufficiently differentiable, so that all these exist. For a general $f\in H^{1,2}$ we have to use the weak derivative in (2).

Comment: @Kevshav Suppose $f$ is smooth and for concreteness let us work in a one dimensional manifold. Then we can define $\frac{d}{dx} f$ by using a coordinate chart as is usually done with no reference to the metric. So how is this the same as $\nabla f= (\partial_i f) g^{ij}\partial_j$ which does explicitly use the metric?

Comment: The objects are not the same. The norms are. (In any dimension:)
$$|\nabla f|^2_{g,TM} = \sum g_{ij} (g^{ik}\partial_k f)(g^{jl}\partial_l f) = \sum g^{ij}(\partial_i f)(\partial_j f) = |\mathrm d f|^2_{g^{-1},T^*M}$$

Comment: Thank you! So it seems that the Poincare inequality can be interpreted as both $$\|u - \overline{u} \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C \|\nabla u \|_{L^p(\Omega)}$$ and $$\|u - \overline{u} \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C \|D u \|_{L^p(\Omega)}$$  where $D$ is the weak derivative and $\nabla$ the Riemannian gradient assuming integrability holds, is that right? That seems like a strong result and I'm surprised it's not explicitly stated more often.

Comment: Perhaps - The first line holds only for differentiable functions, in which case $\nabla u$ is defined, and then the weak derivative $Du$ is already equal to the regular derivative (aka gradient or exterior derivative) of $u$. So to me the two lines you wrote are the same statement whenever the first one exists.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!